# Parsing MySQL date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, datetime, dynamic-arrays

I want to display the date timestamp retrieved from a MySQL database in a HTML table dynamically. I have an array of dates. I am getting date in the following format:

> Mar 10, 2014 6:40:45 AM

How can I get the date as it is and represent it in my HTML table using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that ***Mar 10, 2014 6:40:45 AM*** is your input date format, This code will help:

```
var myDate = new Date('Mar 10, 2014 6:40:45 AM');
var reqDate = ((myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + myDate.getDate() + "/" + myDate.getFullYear());
console.log(reqDate);
```

**output**

```
3/10/2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your clarification that you cannot change the format of the incoming date, you need something like this:

```
var dateParts = isoFormatDateString.split("-");
var jsDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2].substr(0,2));
```